# How to solve the error messages by my calculator?

Tags: python, calculator

I was programming using Ti-84 Plus Ce Texas Instrument Calculator.

I tried to copy my quadratic equation calculator thing from my computer to the calculator for convenience.

The original code is as following:

```
import math

a = int(input("co-efficient of x^2: "))
b = int(input("co-efficient of x: "))
c = int(input("constant: "))

if (b**2 - 4*a*c >= 0):
    rootPart = math.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)
    x1 = (-b + rootPart) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - rootPart) / (2 * a)
    print("{}, {}".format(x1, x2))
    
else:
    x1 = "{} / {}".format("({}+i)".format(str(-b)), str(2 * a))
    x2 = "{} / {}".format("({}-i)".format(str(-b)), str(2 * a))
    print("{}, {}".format(x1, x2))
```

The calculator allows python programming.
However, whenever I tried to run the code, it gives me the following maths error as shown in the image attached.

Error message fro (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Ccd.jpg)

I am sure I didn't copy the code incorrectly. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the code shown in this question

Comment: Code works fine. Error is `syntax line 12` which does suggest either incorrect copying of code or that Ti-84 does not accept some normal syntax. Have you tried just using `print` without the format approach.

Comment: @DarkKnight I am pretty sure the error code is in the link
@user19077881 I am sure I didn't copy the code incorrectly, and I also tried `print` without format